# Feasibility of creating Docker images in Jenkins through shell script instead of using Jenkins file

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am just exploring the implementation of CI/CD pipeline using Kubernetes, Jenkins, Docker Hub and with my private SVN repository. I am exploring the Docker image creating and pushing into Docker Hub automatically when a commit or any SVN operation is done in repository.

Here in examples, I am seeing the creating one pipeline job with adding GitHub repository code repo link and docker hub credentials. And adding one Jenkinsfile in the project root folder as the same position as Dockerfile. Here I had felt one doubt of this image creation method.

Instead of creating Jenkinsfile and Jenkins configuration, can I create the Docker image automatically only by adding shell script in Jenkins?

I am a beginner in build automation. How can I clear my confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on maven projects, then you can easily create Docker images using Docker maven plugin(https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin).

Through Jenkins, you can easily integrate a maven project and execute maven commands which will create the Docker image.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your response sir. Its great pleasure for your reply. I have one doubt on this. If I am committing into my SVN/GitHub , Can I create multiple number of docker images using this docker maven? . Since I need to create multiple docker images by specifying spring active profile - Spring config server method.So In local I am editing Dockerfile each time for creating different images according to config server active profile. So Is possible to create multiple docker images as I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple docker images. One idea is that you can create separate jenkins jobs which will create separate docker images. In jenkins job you can have maven command with command line argument which will eventually pass to the pom.xml. Hope this help. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Ok. Let me confirm your point. Means I need to create separate jobs for each Spring cloud config Profile/Config for creating different images . If I need to launch 5 docker images corresponding to 5 different Config server Profile/Config from same code repo, Then I need to create 5 pipeline job and in command line I need to manage these. Is this your saying ? Let me clarify this sir ?

Comment: Yes, we are on same page. As of now I only know that we can build a single image from a pom.xml using maven build command.
I will try to figure out some better solution and let you know.

Comment: You can go through http://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:build for complete documentation. 
There is one more docker maven plugin https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin, although I haven't use this one.

Comment: Yes. I got your point. Let me explore the Docker Maven in detail. Anyway Thank you Mr. Hemant Singh for your responses and suggestions.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to discuss is that , If I have total 20 microservices , then Do i need to create these 5 different pipeline job for all of these microservices? Something is feeling improper here. Can you revise this your point please?

Comment: Lets suppose I have 6 micro services than I can take the call that they all should be part of same image or 6 images consists of each micro service or I can also group them into 2 images according to their purpose, rate of change etc. 
Now to build an image, we can use maven docker plugin which uses maven pom.xml and internally at execution of build command creates a Dockerfile.

Comment: Now lets suppose I have 2 images each consisting 3 micro services, so I will be building 2 images and if I want to have a separate image one with Java 7 & other one with Java8, in this scenario I will use a single pom.xml which takes java version as an argument. To create 4 images, I need to execute 4 maven commands on these 2 pom.xml which I can achieve through 4 jenkins job or somehow create a script which will execute it. 
We can discuss it further on chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170541/discussion-between-prince-varghese-v-and-hemant-singh).